# redirect only www and root domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have an old domain that I have redirected to a new domain, using

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In reviewing the incoming links to my old site, I found out there are hundreds of spammy links pointing to random sub-domains on my old site.  So, my backlink profile has links to things like adfdfdf.oldsite.com , etc.

I don't want these old spammy links forwarded, as they now point to www.newsite.html, thus giving me spammy links to my new site home page.

What I would like is for the oldsite to only redirect the root domain and the www subdomain, but no other subdomains.

I tried a couple of different configurations but couldn't get one to work properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite.com$ [NC]
```

right bfore your redirect rule.